# Oracle SQL- Insert Statement- SQL Error: ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Tags: sql, string, oracle, datetime, sql-insert

i am trying to to update table but its not accepting NULL. what can I do in order for it to accept NULL? The error im getting is as follow :

```
SQL Error: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
00984. 00000 -  "column not allowed here"
```

the code I implemented is :

```
INSERT into Employees
Values (242,'Anouar','seljouki','seljouki84@gmail.com',0662777081,
19-May-2012,AD_CMMS,16000,NULL,NULL,Null);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`19-May-2012` without surrounding single quotes raises an error, as does `AD_CMMS`. If you want a literal date, I would recommend the `DATE` syntax, like so:

```
INSERT into Employees
Values (
    242,
    'Anouar',
    'seljouki',
    'seljouki84@gmail.com',
    '0662777081',
    DATE '2012-05-19',
    'AD_CMMS',
    16000,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL
);
```

Notes:

- I would strongly recommend enumerating the target columns for `INSERT` in the statement; this makes the query self-explanatory, more flexible and resilient
- `0662777081`, with a leading `0`, makes it look like the target column is of a string-like datatype, so I surrounded it with quotes too; you might need to review that

Comment: Error starting at line : 26 in command - INSERT into Employees Values (242,'Anouar','seljouki','seljouki84@gmail.com','0662777081',date19-May-12, SELECT job_id from JOBS where job_id in('AD_CMMS'),16000,NULL,NULL,Null) Error at Command Line : 28 Column : 1 Error report - SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression 00936. 00000 - "missing expression

Comment: Read about literals in docs, especially about date literal. The correct format is `date '2012-05-19'`

Comment: @AnouarSeljouki: this answers the question that you originally asked, and I would suggest that you accept the answer. Additional questions about how to handle the subquery should be asked as a new question (which you actually did).